# Modernising a traditional windows app environment

Tags: windows, virtualization, application-pools

We're a Windows shop with 3-400 applications in our environment in a standard server/client configuration. We have 600+ Windows servers from 2003 to 2012, predominantly virtual with some physicals around.

I'm currently looking at different ways to move this environment forward, I know DevOps exists for more .NET / Custom apps, but what are our options for treating legacy and more traditional apps that aren't going to go away any time soon? Lift and shift into Azure doesn't seem like an effective option. Looking to ultimately monitor and automate alot of the application services restarts and crashes.

Comment: This is much too broad for a Q&A format. You'll want some consultants to architect you a solution.